# Javascript file locked when breakpoint added

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2003

I'm using Visual Studio 2003. In debug mode, whenever I add a break point in my javascript (js) file, the file then becomes locked so that it can't be edited.

Closing the tab and reopening it seems to unlock it.

What I'd like to know is: why does this happen and is there some kind of setting that would prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by design. When you hit a breakpoint Visual Studio shows a copy of the actual file. You cannot edit it during debugging.

Comment: Dumb design then. Thank you Bill Gates :-)

Comment: It may be not so dumb because there is no way to tell the browser to reload a JavaScript file once you modify it. You need to reload the page in order to to that.

Comment: Yes. But reloading the page on the browser is easy enough. Why not just let users edit the js file with the knowledge that it won't take effect until the page is refreshed. It's all changed from 2005 onwards anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Found this macro which automatically closes and reopens the js page you are on, and moves the cursor back to the line you are on. Hope it comes in useful to someone.

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module AllowJSModify

    Sub ReOpenWindow()
        Try
            'get line no
            Dim objCursorTxtPoint As EnvDTE.TextPoint = GetCursorTxtPnt()
            Dim intLine As Integer = objCursorTxtPoint.Line

            'get current filename
            Dim strActiveWindow = DTE.ActiveWindow.Document.FullName

            'close open file (auto-save)
            DTE.ActiveWindow.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes)

            're-open file
            Dim item As EnvDTE.ProjectItem = DTE.Solution.FindProjectItem(strActiveWindow)
            item.Open()
            item.Document.Activate()

            'go to prev line no
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.GotoLine(intLine)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MsgBox("You are not focused on a line of code.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCursorTxtPnt() As EnvDTE.TextPoint

        Dim objTextDocument As EnvDTE.TextDocument

        Dim objCursorTxtPoint As EnvDTE.TextPoint

        Try

            objTextDocument = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object, EnvDTE.TextDocument)

            objCursorTxtPoint = objTextDocument.Selection.ActivePoint()

        Catch ex As System.Exception

        End Try

        Return objCursorTxtPoint

    End Function

End Module
```